# Tracking breeze.js entity with knockout

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm facing serious memory issue when using knockout with breeze.js entities . 
my system is configured with knockout (breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "ko");).
I noticed after profiling the knockout observation process cost may memory per entity , only for comparison Product entity = 56K with knockout , and 2K without (backingStore).

So I decided to move to backingStore , but this causes me systax problems od knockout , I use the () in many placed (Html and Javascript) also I need the knockout binding functionality .
Is there away to request breeze to make the entity with knockout only when needed.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You can use the `.noTracking()` clause to get untracked entities or you can use two managers that are configured independent of each other and transfer entities between them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,but if I use nottracking or a manager without tracking , I still need the observability of knockout for the screens (add , update...) refreshing the ui , this is my actual problem .